# Как отключить предпросмотр в виджете Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу на странице управления виджетами в окне предпросмотра вывести, что предпросмотр для данного недоступен.
В документации [по ссылке](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/widgets/legacy-widget-block/#displaying-no-preview-available) есть такой пример:

```
class ExampleWidget extends WP_Widget {
    ...
    public function widget( $instance ) {
        if ( ! isset( $instance['name'] ) ) {
            // Name is required, so display nothing if we don't have it.
            return;
        }
?>
        <h3>Name: <?php echo esc_html( $instance['name'] ); ?></h3>
        ...
<?php
    }
...
}
```

Однако, в этом случае, на фронте так же не выводится содержимое виджета.
Если код видоизменить на примерно так:

```
class ExampleWidget extends WP_Widget {
    ...
    public function widget( $instance ) {
        if(is_admin()){
            unset($instance['test']);
        } else {
            $instance['test'] = 'test';
        }
        if ( ! isset( $instance['test'] ) ) {
            // Name is required, so display nothing if we don't have it.
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <h3>Name: <?php echo esc_html( $instance['test'] ); ?></h3>
        ...
        <?php
    }
    ...
}
```

то на странице предпросмотра не выводится ничего — ни содержимого виджета, ни уведомления о недоступности просмотра.
В общем, как вывести что предпросмотр недоступен? Хочу получить вот такое:
[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто проверить присутствие в админпанели:

```
class ExampleWidget extends WP_Widget {
    ...
    public function widget( $instance ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            return;
        }
?>
        <h3>Name: <?php echo esc_html( $instance['name'] ); ?></h3>
        ...
<?php
    }
...
}
```